# Find columns with unique constraints in a table

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm migrating from MySQL to PostgreSQL. I need to find all columns that have unique constraints in a table. What is the equivalent of below query in PostgreSQL?

```
SELECT column_name, index_name
FROM information_schema.statistics
WHERE table_schema='db' and table_name='tb' and non_unique=0 and index_name != 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasG! The link definitely helps. I found the answer from Adrian below exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using information_schema:

```
SELECT
    cu.column_name,
    tc.constraint_name
FROM
    information_schema.table_constraints AS tc
JOIN 
    information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS cu 
ON 
    tc.constraint_name = cu.constraint_name
WHERE
    constraint_type = 'UNIQUE'
AND 
    tc.table_catalog = 'db'
AND 
    tc.table_schema = 'public'
AND 
    tc.table_name = 'tb';
```

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Klaver! Exactly what I need, though I had to make a small change in the `WHERE` clause `AND tc.table_catalog = 'db' AND tc.table_schema = 'public' `